# Proof that if two lines are parallel then $A_1$ = $A_2$ and $B_1$ = $B_2$?

Tags: analytic-geometry

Let two lines to be parallel **in their general form**.

$L_1$ : $A_1 x$ + $B_1 y$ + $C_1$

$L_2$ : $A_2 x$ + $B_2 y$ + $C_2$

Now i wish to prove $A_1$ = $A_2$ and $B_1$ = $B_2$

But i can only think of the prove in my head, not sure how to write it mathematically.

Comment: May be $L_1 = A_1 x +B_1 \color{red}{ y} +C_1$?

Comment: copy paste error

Comment: This is not true. We can conclude, however, that $A_1 B_2 = A_2 B_1$.

Comment: @Travis https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dnc0szxvxb Look here it is true.

Comment: It should be L1: A1x + B1y +C1 = 0 rather than L1 = A1x+B1y+C1.

Comment: Ok i will edit it. Sorry i dont know so minute details.

Comment: That link shows the opposite: In fact, it demonstrates that given a line $A x + B y + C = 0$, the equation $(\lambda A) x + (\lambda B) y + (\lambda C) = 0$, where $\lambda \neq 0$, defines the same line. If we take $\lambda \neq 1$, then the coefficients of $x$ in the two equations are different, contradicting your claim.

Comment: Now three people have showed you that your claim is not true, and yet you keep saying it is and sending "proof" of this claim, which is just one example in which your claim holds. Can you accept that your claim is not true?

Comment: @B.Pasternak how ? Look if we take two equal lines Say $A_1 x$ + $B_1 x$ = 0, we can offset one of the lines by any amount $C_1$ and then the lines will be parallel. That is now line $A_1 x$ + $B_1 x$ = 0 and $A_1 x$ + $B_1 x$ +  $C_1$ = 0 are parallel.

Comment: Do you understand that the implication (assuming $A_2\neq0$ and $B_2\neq0$) $\frac{A_1}{A_2}=\frac{B_1}{B_2}\implies A_1=A_2\wedge B_1=B_2$ does not hold in general (consider $\frac{1}{2}=\frac{2}{4}$), but the implication $A_1=A_2\wedge B_1=B_2\implies\frac{A_1}{A_2}=\frac{B_1}{B_2}$ (assuming $A_2\neq0$ and $B_2\neq0$) does hold in general?

Comment: Ok, let two lines be parallel, $A_1 x$ + $B_1 y$ + $C_1$ = 0 and $A_2 x$ + $B_2 y$ + $C_2$ = 0, now the second line can be written in form $A_1 x$ + $B_1 y$ + $\frac{C_2}{a}$ = 0, where $a$ is any real number. Do you agree with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your claim is wrong.

Write the formula of each line in the form $y=mx +c$

$L_1: y= (\frac{-A_1}{B_1})x + (\frac{-C_1}{B_1})$

$L_2: y= (\frac{-A_2}{B_2})x + (\frac{-C_2}{B_2})$

For two lines to parallel theirs slopes($m$) must be equal.

So, by comparison, it would be seen that $\frac{A_1}{B_1}=\frac{A_2}{B_2}$,

which doesn't necessarily $\Rightarrow A_1=A_2$ and $B_1=B_2$

Comment: Let a line $A_1 x$ + $B_1 y $+ $C_1$ = 0

Now if you check in a graphing calculator then 

$A_1 x$ + $B_1 y $+ $C_2$ = 0

will be parallel to first line.

So that means parallel lines have $x$ and $y$ - coefficient equal

Comment: @ritwiksinha Check the edits

Comment: look here, https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dnc0szxvxb

This is what i mean.

Comment: @ritwiksinha What's the confusion? Dividing by $2$ is nothing but the same as $\frac{A_1}{A_2}=\frac{B_1}{B_2}=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: then you can see that $A_1$ = $A_2$ and same for the other.

Comment: @ritwiksinha I don't get what you are trying to say.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39784/discussion-between-ritwik-sinha-and-roby5).

Answer (score 1):

Let $A_1, A_2, B_1,B_2 \not = 0$. Then

$$L_1 || L_2 \Leftrightarrow \frac {A_1}{A_2}=\frac {B_1}{B_2}$$
**Proof:**

Let $\frac {A_1}{A_2}\not=\frac {B_1}{B_2}$. Then the system of equations 
$$\begin{cases}
 A_1 x + B_1 y + C_1=0,
\\
 A_2 x + B_2 y + C_2=0
\end{cases}
$$

has a solution. A point that belongs to both straight. The contradiction (because the lines are parallel)

**Addition:**
For example:

$l_1: 2x+3y+7=0$ and $4x+6y+7=0$

[image]

Comment: This solution seems to presuppose that $A_2, B_2$ are both nonzero.

Comment: Yes, these cases must be added separately

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but i mean in general form. that is we can divide the second equation by two and then $A_1$ = $A_2$ and $B_1$ = $B_2$

Comment: Look here  https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dnc0szxvxb